# OpenFOAM- write interval changed after restarting simulation

Tags: hpc, openfoam

I am running a pimpleFoam simulation on a supercomputer. I have to submit it as a job which has an allocated time. The simulation I was running ran out of this allocated time. So then I restarted it with `startFrom latestTime;` and `writeInterval   0.01;` in the controlDict, it started printing out many intermediate time results which did not happen during the first run. Following is my `controlDict` file which I did not change between the two runs:

> /*--------------------------------*- C++
> -*----------------------------------*\ | =========                 |                                                 | | \      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
> | |  \    /   O peration     | Version:  v2006
> | |   \  /    A nd           | Website:  [www.openfoam.com](http://www.openfoam.com)
> | |    \/     M anipulation  |
> |
> *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ FoamFile {
> version     2.0;
> format      ascii;
> class       dictionary;
> location    "system";
> object      controlDict; } // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
>
> //application     icoFoam; application     pimpleFoam;
>
> startFrom       latestTime; //startFrom       startTime;
>
> startTime       0;
>
> stopAt    nextWrite; //stopAt          endTime;
>
> endTime         15;
>
> deltaT          1e-4;
>
> //writeControl    timeStep; writeControl    adjustableRunTime;
>
> //writeInterval   100; writeInterval   0.01;
>
> purgeWrite      0;
>
> writeFormat     ascii;
>
> writePrecision  6;
>
> writeCompression off;
>
> timeFormat      general;
>
> timePrecision   6;
>
> runTimeModifiable true;
>
> //PIMPLE adjustTimeStep   yes;
>
> maxCo     2;
>
> maxDeltaT     0.01;
>
> //
> ************************************************************************* //
>
> functions {
>
> }

Examples of what I mean are the two following pictures:

[image]

[image]

I am using OpenFOAM v10.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand the "before" and "after" of the settings.